# What happens when I provide a function with the parent of the subtype argument it's expecting?

Tags: vhdl

While trying to figure out the specifics of the shift_right function from the numeric_std package I noticed that the count argument is of the subtype NATURAL:

```
function shift_right(ARG: UNSIGNED; COUNT: NATURAL) return UNSIGNED is
begin
  if (ARG'length<1) then return NAU; end if;
  return UNSIGNED(XSRL(STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(ARG),COUNT));
  end;
```

However when calling the function I can also provide an INTEGER which in contrast to NATURAL can hold a negative number.

Example of calling code that succesfully compiles:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity ExampleCode is
    port 
    (
        clk    : in std_logic;
        input  : in signed(15 downto 0);
        shift  : in signed(3 downto 0);
        output : out signed(15 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture rtl of ExampleCode is

begin

    ProcessExample : process(clk)
    begin
        if (rising_edge(clk)) then
            output <= shift_right(input, to_integer(shift));
        end if;
    end process;

 end rtl;
```

The numeric_std package shows that if you use to_integer with a signed argument that it returns an integer:

```
  function TO_INTEGER ( ARG: SIGNED) return INTEGER;
```

My questions are;

- Does VHDL always allow parents of subtypes to be provided as arguments to functions?
- When it does allow a parent type, how does it resolve the imposed constraints of the subtype?

Comment: IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.4 Function calls "Evaluation of a function call includes evaluation of the actual parameter expressions specified in the call and evaluation of the default expressions associated with formal parameters of the function that do not have actual parameters associated with them. In both cases, the resulting value shall belong to the subtype of the associated formal parameter. (If the formal parameter is of an unconstrained or partially constrained composite type, then any undefined index ranges of subelements of the formal parameter are determined as described in 5.3.2.2.)"

Comment: 5. Types "The set of possible values for an object of a given type can be subjected to a condition that is called a constraint (the case where the constraint imposes no restriction is also included); a value is said to satisfy a constraint if it satisfies the corresponding condition. A subtype is a type together with a constraint. A value is said to belong to a subtype of a given type if it belongs to the type and satisfies the constraint; the given type is called the base type of the subtype."

Comment: I'm downloading modelsim right now to check how it will respond, quartus on the other hand will happily allow me to include this into my design without as much as a warning. How come quartus II wil allow this behaviour if a simulator deems it wrong? I feel like I'm making an assumption here that is invalid about what should be doing what..

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is very detailed, but I think goes down a bit of a rabbit hole, when your specific questions can be answered more succinctly. I have answered from a perspecitve of what will practically happen in a real tool that you might use, as opposed to trying to re-interpret the language standard.

An important feature of a `subtype` is that there is automatic 'conversion'<sup>+</sup> to and from the parent type. The example below clearly shows this with an enumerated type. The same automatic conversion would be invoked when passing a parent-type parameter to a function that expects the sub-type.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity e is
end;

architecture a of e is

  type r is (A, B, C, D);
  subtype rs is r range A to C;

  signal x1 : r := B;
  signal x2 : r := D;
  signal xs : rs;

begin

  process
  begin
    xs <= x1; -- Fine.
    wait for 1 ns;
    xs <= x2; -- Run-time error, "Value 3 is out of range 0 to 2".
    wait;
  end process;

end;
```

## Does VHDL always allow parents of subtypes to be provided as arguments to functions?

From the above, yes, it does, but in many tools, you will get an error if the automatic type conversion cannot succeed, as it obviously cannot in the second assignment in the example. Note that if `x2` was a `constant`, a tool could work out that the conversion is not going to be possible, and thrown up a compile-time error then instead.

The same applies with `natural` and `integer`; since `natural` is defined as `subtype natural is integer range 0 to integer'high`, `natural` in a sense *is* an `integer`, so automatic 'conversion' is simple and reasonable as long as the integer is not outside the natural's range.

## When it does allow a parent type, how does it resolve the imposed constraints of the subtype?

Whether standardised or not, a particular tool might implement this in a variety of ways, so you might see different behavior for out-of-range parent-typed values with different tools.

For example, when I tried with ModelSim, it appears that its conversion from `integer` to `natural` simply copies the value, meaning that `shift_right` will surprisingly work with a negative value in that tool, if the shift amount integer is *not* a constant (at least for version 10.7e).

Obviously it is not sensible to rely on a particular behavior, but regardless of behavior, using a sub type can offer you more protection than just using base types throughout a design.

---

<sup>+</sup> It's not really conversion in VHDL, but if you've used pretty much any other language, this is how you will tend to refer to it.

Comment: You've missed the mark a bit. Scalars don't have implicit subtype conversion (5.3.2.2), applicable to array index ranges. There is a requirement that the actual's value belongs to the subtype of the formal (they are of the same base type, 4.5.1, "A subtype is a type together with a constraint.", 5.1). That can be detected (1.3.3, "Conditions are deemed erroneous only when it is impossible in general to detect the condition during the processing of the language.") during the function call evaluation (9.3.4), shall is mandatory (1.3.1). but 9.3.4 doesn't specify this produces an error (1.3.1).

Comment: Thanks @user1155120. I'm sure you are correct but your comments are extremely difficult to understand with no copy of the LRM. It sounds like if I simply replace languange ilke 'will throw an error' with 'will fail', I will have satisfied your comment? If not, feel free to edit or suggest further :)

Comment: A type is a set of values and operations. A subtype is a type and a constraint. You don't convert integer to natural they're the same type already.  Subtype is not part of overload resolution. The base type is used in finding overloads for functions (which can also implement operator overloads) and  enumeration literals. A subtype describes a subset of the values of a type or subset of index range for an array whose value is the value of it's elements in an index range which can be subtype converted in assignment, initial or value expressions, or association based on matching elements.

Comment: So no, there is no simple edit to make your answer correct (and Tim should stop digging). Neither the question nor it's answers demonstrate an understanding of what is meant by 'VHDL is strongly typed', it's not well described in literature other than the standard. There is no requirement in the standard that providing a parameter value outside the subtype constraint generates an error in a function call. See the -2008 description of the `srl`  and `sra` operators. What should the SHIFT_RIGHT[signed , integer] return signed result be? (The question isn't specific.)

Comment: @user1155120 Thanks for the detail. "integer to natural [are] the same type already" - I have said almost exactly this in my answer. "There is no requirement in the standard that providing a parameter value outside the subtype constraint generates an error in a function call." - this is *exactly* what I'm saying in my last two sentences; using subtypes is valuable regardless of how a particular tool handles them. I have made some edits to reflect that this is a *practical* answer.

Comment: Yet you still mention conversion from integer to natural. There's a profane childish joke trying to convey a supermarket produce department has no bananas. Here there's no conversion.

Comment: @user1155120 I have specifically included a clause stating that it's not actually conversion, maybe you missed it.